let $id := request:get-parameter("id","") What could be wrong to cause $id not to get the value from get-parameter? How can I fix it?
I am working through a basic exercise which you can find here https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/beginners-guide-to-xrx-v4).
Problem: I think the problem is with the get-parameter() function.
It returns:
http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/terms/views/view-item.xq?id=%20%20%20%20 1

This value 1 at the end doesn’t seem to be getting picked up by $id as it doesn’t give me the data for the terms.
Here is the xml file:
       <term>                         
       <id>         1         </id>    
        <term-name>    Declarative Programming        </term-name>   
                   
        <definition>   A style of programming that allows users to declare their  
                                requirements (what they want done) and leave out the details of 
                                how the function should be   performed.                         </definition>                  
<publish-status-code>             published         </publish-status-code>         
</term>

Here is xquery that I am running:
view-item.xq
   xquery version "3.1";    
   declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";     
   declare option exist:serialize "method=xhtml media-type=text/html indent=yes";     
   let $id := request:get-parameter("id","")    
   let $term := collection('/db/apps/terms/data')/term\[id=$id\]        
    (:  let $term := collection('/db/apps/terms/data')/term\[id = $id\]:)    
    (:  :let $term := collection('/db/apps/terms/data')/term\[id=1\]:)      
    return       
    <html>       
    <head>           
    <title>Term {$term/id/text()}</title>        
    </head>        
    <body>           
    <h1>Term {$term/id/text()}</h1> 
          <b>Term ID: </b> {$term/id/text()}</br> 
          <b>Term Name: </b> {$term/term-name/text()}</br>      
          <b>Term Definition: </b> {$term/definition/text()}</br>      
          <b>Term Status: </b> {$term/publish-status-code/text()}</br>        
    </body>    
    </html>

   

[Current Output with no data returned for id 1](https://i.sstatic.net/7ofAN6ne.png)

Your XML does have spaces around the 1, so when you ask for <id> you also get these spaces. Looks like they get url-encoded to %20s, and probably similar code discards the the trailing spaces from the url. Check for a trim function in xquery; IIRC there is such a thing.

As mentioned, you have a lot of spaces before the "1" in your URL parameter (the %20s).
The trim function is part of the functx library that is either installed by default or available as a package. You can import it by:
xquery version "3.1";

declare namespace request="http://exist-db.org/xquery/request";
import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com";

let $id := request:get-parameter("id","") => functx:trim()
...

If your index assumes that @id is an integer, pipe that to xs:integer like so:
let $id := request:get-parameter("id","") => functx:trim() => xs:integer()
Hope this helps.
